# Openfire additional user's fields

Tags: xmpp, openfire, strophe

I built a web chat based on **openfire** + **strophe.js** and I want to use phone number as a login for user. I didn't find something about how to add additional fields for openfire (for example checkbox for verification telephone number).

How can I do that ?

Maybe using $ajax + php + additional data base?

Comment: Your question is really too broad going from adding new fields to user definition in Openfire to phone number validation...

Answer (score 2):

You can add additional fields to user info on a XMPP server (Openfire too) with some [Strophe plugins](https://github.com/strophe/strophejs-plugins):

- using a [VCard](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0054.html) associated to the user (check https://github.com/strophe/strophejs-plugins/blob/master/vcard),
- using [Private XML Storage](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0049.html) for the user (check https://github.com/strophe/strophejs-plugins/blob/master/private)

Answer (score 0):

For XMPP Login, you need username/password, So you can make the phonenumber as username.

And if you will do that, then definitely you will have to validate phone number yourself. You can use https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber from Google for this.